# How to execute additional code for selected functions in lua

Tags: lua

Is there any clean and elegant way to 'incject' code into existing functions in lua?
The problem is that we have a table with many functions and we have to perform a simple logging of their arguments and their results. And the obvious solution to copypaste the line which would perform logging to each of them doesn't seems right and is going to be timeconsuming.
I was trying to use metatables mechanism i.e. create table that would act as a wrapper but I could not find a way to execute code from its level:

```
log = function(msg) trace(msg) end

mapl = {} --wrapper table
mt = { 
    __index = map; -- map is the original table with many methods
                   -- is there a way to call log function here?
} 

setmetatable(mapl, mt)

mapl:getMap(params) -- call to a getMap function in map via mapl wrapper
```

Or perhaps this approach is completely wrong? Maybe there is already a mechanism to trace/log funciton calls I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your initial approach, one way to do it is like this:

```
local log = function(func_name, ...)
    print("Calling "..func_name.." with args:")
    for i,v in ipairs {...} do
        print(i,v)
    end
end

-- original map with functions to cover
local map = {
    getMap = function() print "original getMap" end,
    setNode = function() print "original setNode" end
}

-- logged interface
local mapl = {}

-- helper returning new logging wrapper
local function grab_args(_, func_name)
    local func = map[func_name]

    -- sanity check
    if type(func) == "function" then
        local wrapper = function(_, ...)
            log(func_name, map, ...)
            return func(map, ...)
        end
        -- cache wrapper for further usage
        mapl[func_name] = wrapper
        return wrapper
    end

    -- just return non-function values from map
    return func
end

-- setup interface
setmetatable(mapl, {__index = grab_args})


-- test logging
mapl:getMap(1,2,3)
mapl:setNode(42)
```

Few notes on sample. You called functions as `mapl:getMap()`, with colon. So this sample substitutes `mapl` with `map` on actual call to original functions. If you need to call it with dot, `mapl.getMap()`, tinker with wrapper creation, in `local wrapper = function()`.

Comment: Brilliant! This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately it seems that arguments aren't passed to grab_args function in metatable for me.
In grab_args(_, func_name, ...) the '...' is always nil

Comment: What do mean, "not passed" ?

Comment: When calling for eample. mapl:getMap(1,2,3) I expected 1,2,3 to be passed to grab_args, so I can then call original function with ... as param. Instead of that ... is always nil.

Comment: It is passed. Probably you've altered sample, since I did tests before posting answer, here's link to ideone: http://ideone.com/cGQzoW  Note also that since you call function with colon, first argument will be table that stored function, and in sample I've replaced mapl with map, since function might depend on that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you don't get args to grab_args. Indeed, that function will only create (and cache) new wrapper for function. Actual args will be captured when function is actually called. Ignore `...` in grab_args arguments. I've updated sample.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Although I still don't get it how those arguments are magically passed to original function. Lua is still big unknown for me :)

Comment: That's pretty simple. Construct `mapl:getMap(args)` is actually composed of two actions:  `local func = mapl["getMap"]; func(mapl, args)`. So first we alter first action by using __index metamethod to return wrapper that will do extra actions before calling actual function. And in second action that wrapper will do some extra work, and then just pass through its arguments to real function.